# Using HTML textfield to pass a GET parameter to PHP file

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a GET parameter to a PHP file , by data typed in a text field. I want something like this :

```
<form id="Form1" action="action.php?nameExample=textFieldData" method="get">
```

the textfield is out of this form that's why I need to affect the value of the textfield into get PHP parameters so I can send it with another data in the same msg

the textfield code :

```
Username: <input type="text" name="nameExample"><br>
```

anyway to do it ?

Comment: You can't use get parameters in a form action attribute.

Comment: Dont you want to use session?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$_GET` parameters in an HTML form action attribute if the `<form method='get'`. Use `<input type='hidden' name='nameExample' value='whatever' />`, or better yet, use AJAX without a form.

Comment: You can, but the form method has to be 'post' then

Comment: When using `get` as form method, the form inputs replace the whole query string (= the query string in the form action gets lost and only the form fields will be available in `$_GET`). When using `post` as method, the original query string will not be modified, so the parameters from the form action are available in `$_GET` while the form fields are in `$_POST`. There are use cases for it, e.g. pass a step/action/session ID via the query string while passing the real data in POST. If it makes sense or not, technically it's okay.

Comment: `$_GET['nameExample']` would be `'whatever'`.

Comment: Sure, your example works. I just said that it is okay to have a query string in a form action when the method is `post` (because you wrote that he "can't use `$_GET` parameters in an HTML form action attribute", which is not correct for all cases)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want to. The JS code copies the value of an external input field to a hidden input field.

HTML:

```
<form action="action.php" method="get" id="Form1">
    <input type="text" name="otherData" value="xxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="nameExample" value="" id="nameExampleCopy">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

Username: <input type="text" name="nameExample" id="nameExampleOriginal">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('Form1').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    var originalElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleOriginal');
    var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleCopy');
    hiddenElement.value = originalElement.value;
});
```

But you should think about some points:

- Is `get` the right method here? It sounds like `post` could be better.
- Is it semantically a good idea to pass a value from outside the form inside it? We don't know your application, but generally it is a good idea to have all submitted data inside the form. As HTTP pointed out in his comment, sessions could also help with that.

Comment: didn't work :/ it print only the first from content here is my php file 

`<?php
echo $_POST['otherData'];
print "\n";
echo $_POST['nameExample'];

?>`

and i included my js like this : 

`<script src="bilal.js"></script>`

Comment: I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/ujstcbja/) for you. If you fill in some data and submit the form, you see that the opened URL contains the nameExample parameter, so this script should work. Perhaps you changed the IDs or name of the form in your HTML etc.?